# Setting proportional autolayout margins

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am an iOS developer and I would want to know how to improve `autolayout` proportional margins in order to the screen was watched as same in iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6+ both.

If I set a view leading 40 px to another view, in iPhone 4 it's will be too separated and in iPhone 6 it's will be too close.

I read about implementing dummy views glued to that view and use width and height proportial to superview, but this is not a good solution in complex screens because the screen will be full of views and it's will be a madness.

I looked for all tutorials but I can't find anything about this. Could you tell me the best way to improve this feature?

Comment: Are you interested in doing it programmatically? Lets say you set a leading constraint between two views and you want its value to be 20pt on 320pt-screen (ex. iPhone 5). If you create the constraint from code or you have proper IBOutlet for it, you can make it proportional for all kinds of screens by calling once:
`theConstraint.constant = theConstraint.constant * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 320` which in result gives 23.4375pt leading space for 375pt screen. Less dummy views, but much more code when having many constraints.

Comment: That's not possible, because of the complexity of the screens. I have about 100 items on display and i think it would be more complex to do it by code. Really Apple has not thought of this? or i am wrong?